# Common Lisp - Function that builds, from a list of numbers, the list of more, smaller or equal to a given number

Tags: function, lisp, common-lisp

I having trouble with this function, 
I would like a function which
returns a list of number inferior for a given a number.

What I did so far,

```
(defun inf (n l)
(cond
((not l) 0)
((>= n (car l))(cons n (inf n(cdr l))))
(cons (car l) (inf n (cdr l))) ))
```

But it keeps returns

```
(inf 12 '(12 5 3))
(12 12 10)
```

Instead of :

```
(inf 12 '(12 5 3 53 45))
(12 5 3)
```

What did I miss ?

Comment: Please indent your code properly. Use Emacs if necessary.

Comment: The code compiles with a warning: undefined variable `cons`, the one in what should be the default case of your `cond`.

Comment: The question summary, question text, and the attempted
implementation, specify ***three*** different problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A not-so-obvious way to solve the same problem using Common Lisp's existing functions is to pass a comparison operator to [`REMOVE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rm_rm.htm).

```
(remove 10 '(0 3 5 11 22 10 22 3 2) :test #'<)
```

The above removes all elements "equal" to 10 according to `#'<`, which are thus all elements `u` such that `(< 10 u)` holds. In other words, all elements strictly above 10:

```
(0 3 5 10 3 2)
```

It turns out that there is an example of this in the section linked above:

```
(remove 3 '(1 2 4 1 3 4 5) :test #'>) =>  (4 3 4 5)
```

*Edit: since this is now the accepted answer, note also that this approach is probably hard to read, be careful when using it (add a comment, etc.)*.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the function you posted does not behave the way you claim.
The 1st invocation returns `(12 12 12 . 0)` (because you return `0` instead of `nil` in the 1st [`cond`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_cond.htm) clause)
and the second invocation raises an exception

> COND: variable CONS has no value

because you got `cond` syntax wrong.

Second, the question summary, question text, and the attempted
implementation, specify ***three*** different problems.

Here is a fix for your code (I replaced 
[`car` and `cdr`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_car_c.htm) with
[`first`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_firstc.htm) and
[`rest`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rest.htm) for pedagogical reasons):

```
(defun inf (n l)
  (cond
    ((not l) ())                ; return empty list
    ((>= n (first l))
     (cons n (inf n (rest l))))
    (t
     (cons (first l) (inf n (rest l))))))
```

If this is, in fact, what you want, you can implement in a more
idiomatic way:

```
(defun inf-1 (n l)
  (and l (cons (max n (first l)) (inf-1 n (rest l)))))
```

or even

```
(defun inf-2 (n l)
  (mapcar (lambda (x) (max n x)) l))
```

If you actually want the list of numbers less than the given one, you
can use [`remove`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rm_rm.htm):

```
(remove 12 '(12 5 3 100) :test #'<=)
==> (5 3)
```